# Finding the single unknown in an equation

Tags: java, equation, algebra

I need a library to be able to parse an equation an give me the result giving the inputs.

For example something like this:

```
String equation = "5 = 6 / z"; 

EquationSolver solver = new EquationSolver(equation); 

double result = solver.getResult(); 

System.out.println("result: " + result);
```

And evaluates to: 6/5

Is there any kind of library for java that can do that for me?
Basically I need the program to isolate the single unknown variable in an arbitrary equation...

Thanks
Thomas

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is a computer algebra system.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_computer_algebra_systems#Operating_system_support) lists some options. I would check out [Java Algebra System](http://krum.rz.uni-mannheim.de/jas/)

Answer (score 1):

You need a Java expression Library for this.
I found [MVEL](http://mvel.codehaus.org/) to be a good Java Expression Library

You can check this link for other java expression libraries.
http://java-source.net/open-source/expression-languages

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at JPELite.

[JEPLite: java expression parser enlited](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jeplite/).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you'll find one that's as easy to use as you want, but http://jscl-meditor.sourceforge.net/#mozTocId312653 appears to provide polynomial solving: let me know if that works for you (and how!).

Alternatively [JScience](http://jscience.org/api/index.html?org/jscience/mathematics/vector/package-summary.html) may do what you want.

Comment: I've tried to figure out JScience but found it very poorly documented...I can't find samples or anything to guide me :(